# How to go to another component when I click a button in Material Ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am working on Material Ui, In my project I have one component In that I have a button, Now If I click the button, then I have to go to another component, How can achieve this in Material Ui.

I installed react-router-dom and everything

This is my code Mobiles.js

```
import React from "react";
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const AddButton = () => {
  return (
    <IconButton>
      <AddIcon background="primary"></AddIcon>
    </IconButton>
  );
};

export default function Mobiles() {
  return (
    <Link>
      <AddButton to="/products"></AddButton>
    </Link>
  );
}
```

I created products component and written in App.js.

If I am not clear with my doubt, please put a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `to` to `Link` and not your component.

```
import React from "react";
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const AddButton = () => {
  return (
    <IconButton>
      <AddIcon background="primary"></AddIcon>
    </IconButton>
  );
};

export default function Firms() {
  return (
    <Link to="/products">
      <AddButton />
    </Link>
  );
}
```

Another way of doing this is to use the `useHistory` Hook from `react-router-dom`

```
import React from "react";
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const AddButton = ({ to }) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
    <IconButton onClick={() => history.push(to)}>
      <AddIcon background="primary"></AddIcon>
    </IconButton>
  );
};

export default function Firms() {
  return (
      <AddButton to="/products"/>
  );
}
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

(Without Using router Logic)

Create a Parent component with a button Click function
pass the function as prop to the Current component,

The Button Click Function will Change some value in parent component and using Conditional rendering the New Component can be rendered in the position of the Current Component

Answer (score 0):

Change your Mobiles code and use `to="/products"` to Link like this `<Link to="/products"></Link>`

```
export default function Mobiles() {
  return (
    <Link to="/products">
      <AddButton />
    </Link>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use onClick and useHistory hook, something like this should work:

```
import React from "react";
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const AddButton = ({route}) => {

const history = useHistory();
const handleClick = () => history.push(route);

  return (
    <IconButton onClick={handleClick}>
      <AddIcon background="primary"></AddIcon>
    </IconButton>
  );
};

export default function Mobiles() {
  return (
      <AddButton route="/products"></AddButton>
  );
}
```